# SQL Server Sum table fields based on params

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table containing values from 12 different months

```
Table
{
   January INT,
   February INT,
   etc.
}
```

and I need to sum values from specific months which numbers I keep in table (the number of months to sum can vary from 1 to 12):

```
    DECLARE @Months TABLE
    (
        Number INT
    )
```

so I'll surely need a big case and CTE but I don't really know how to achieve this.

Comment: normalize your data to `CREATE Table Month (Month int, Value int)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The case statement isn't that bad:

```
select sum((case when m.month = 1 then Jan else 0 end) +
           (case when m.month = 2 then Feb else 0 end) +
           . . .
           (case when m.month = 12 then Dec else 0 end)
          )
from atable a cross join
     @Months m;
```

You might want a `group by` as well.  The above will return only one row for the entire table.